# Timer with update to the first decimal

Tags: timer, dart, flutter, setstate

I'm trying to make this timer work. Sorry for the mess but a lot of attemps. What is the best way to make it? I'm starting to get confused. I would like to have that time = 30 to go up to 0 with updates of 0.1 and play an alarm sound then.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'dart:ui';
 import 'dart:async';

 class TimerButton extends StatefulWidget {
   final int time = 30;


   @override
   _TimerButtonState createState() => _TimerButtonState();
 }

 class _TimerButtonState extends State<TimerButton> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     return Container(
       margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
       height: 135.0,
       width: 135.0,
       child: new RaisedButton(
        elevation: 100.0,
         color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.8),
         highlightElevation: 0.0,
         onPressed: () {
           startTimer(widget.time);

         };
         splashColor: Colors.red,
         highlightColor: Colors.red,
         //shape: RoundedRectangleBorder e tutto il resto uguale
         shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
             side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2.5),
             borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
         child: new Text(
           "${_start}",
           style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: "Minim", fontSize: 50.0),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
 }

 int startTimer(int time){
   Timer _timer;
   int _start = time;

   const oneSec = const Duration(milliseconds: 100);
   _timer = new Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer timer) {
     _TimerButtonState().setState((){
       if (_start < 0.1) {
         timer.cancel();
       } else {
         _start = _start - 100;
       }
     });
   });

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:async';

const oneTick = const Duration(milliseconds: 100);

class TimerButton extends StatefulWidget {
  /// desired duration in seconds
  final int time;

  TimerButton({Key key, this.time: 30}): super(key:key);

  @override
  TimerButtonState createState() => _TimerButtonState();
}

class TimerButtonState extends State<TimerButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  /// timer instance
  Timer _timer;

  /// holds number of millis till end
  int _millisLeft;

  /// holds total desired duration
  Duration _totalDuration;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // create convertable duration object with desired number of seconds
    _totalDuration = Duration(seconds: widget.time);

    resetTimer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      height: 135.0,
      width: 135.0,
      child: new RaisedButton(
        elevation: 100.0,
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.8),
        highlightElevation: 0.0,
        onPressed: () {
          // reset
          resetTimer();
          startTimer();
        },
        splashColor: Colors.red,
        highlightColor: Colors.red,
        //shape: RoundedRectangleBorder e tutto il resto uguale
        shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2.5),
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
        child: new Text(
          formatTime(_millisLeft),
          style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: "Minim", fontSize: 50.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void resetTimer() {
    setState(() {
      // cancel if any
      _timer?.cancel();
      // reset value to begin from
      _millisLeft = _totalDuration.inMilliseconds;
    });
  }

  void startTimer() {
    setState(() {
      _timer = new Timer.periodic(oneTick, onTick);
    });
  }

  void onTick(Timer timer) {
    print(_millisLeft);

    setState(() {
      // stop when lower then 1 tick duration
      if (_millisLeft < oneTick.inMilliseconds) {
        timer.cancel();
      } else {
        // subtract one tick
        _millisLeft -= oneTick.inMilliseconds;
      }
    });
  }

  /// divide by 1000 to сonvert millis to seconds (in double precision),
  /// then use toStringAsFixed(number of precision digits after comma)
  String formatTime(int ms) {
    return (ms / 1000).toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
}
```

usage

```
TimerButton()
```

or

```
TimerButton(seconds:420)
```

*Added to answer your comment*:

1) To be able reset it from outside: 
In a separate file e.g. `keys.dart` register a global key (do it once per app, i mean do not repeat this line)

```
GlobalKey<TimerButtonState> timerKey = GlobalKey<TimerButtonState>();
```

Then when you're creating a timer pass this key to it

```
... your screen or whatever
import '../keys.dart'
...
TimerButton(key: timerKey, time:50)
...
onClick: timerKey.currentState.resetTimer //shorthand syntax
onClick: () {
        timerKey.currentState.resetTimer();
        }  // for sure
```

2) To pass values from widget to parent:

```
class TimerButton extends StatefulWidget {
  /// desired duration in seconds
  final int time;
  final Function(Duration) onTicked;


  TimerButton({Key key, this.time: 30, this.onTicked}): super(key:key);

  @override
  TimerButtonState createState() => _TimerButtonState();
}
...
//in state:
...
void onTick(Timer timer) {
    print(_millisLeft);

    setState(() {
      if (_millisLeft < oneTick.inMilliseconds) {
        timer.cancel();
        widget.onStopped();  // tell whoever interested that it's stopped
      } else {
        // subtract one tick
        _millisLeft -= oneTick.inMilliseconds;
        widget.onTicked(_millisLeft);  // tell about updates
      }
    });
  }
// in parent:
...
TimerButton(key: timerKey,
            time:50,
            onStop: (){ parent.doSmthOnStop();},
            onTicked: (int millisLeft) {
                         setState((){
                         parentStateVariable = millisLeft;
                      });
                  })
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do it but this is so much cleaner. I will study your code well. However a problem I had was that I wanted to call the reset timer from outside this class, from another class. How can I pass function in the _TimerButtonState outside of it?
I've seen that to pass data in I have to use the initState and then use widget.variable for example. But I don't know how I can pass those values or any function i make inside that class to be called from outside.

Comment: updated an answer. ( to use a key, your State name should **not** start with an underscore.

Comment: ah ok. Just that i know that putting that underscore means that is private to that class if i'm not wrong, however i tought there was some kind of common practice to keep that class private and access some way to those variable. For example a function outside the class that is not private can access those variables but the class itself remains private like is common use. Am I correct? Or just without underscore?

Comment: Right, you can create a key in same file with state and leave _State private, not sure whether it makes any difference, because your state is already exposed via key anyway, I just prefer storing all keys in separate file :)

Comment: little question. You see I have a timer displayed in a RaisedButton widget. I create 6 instances of that widget in the main page. Everyone with a different starting time. And until now it's all ok. How can i start or stop each one separately? Or I have to create a key for everyone. I would like to make that only a timer each time is active. And if you press another the old one pressed and active stops and resets, and the last pressed only starts like normal. If you can just explain the best workflow not the code. If you can the code is better but that would be enough for starting working on it

Comment: I would introduce a new bool widget argument 'isPaused', and use it inside onTick to decide whether to subtract ms from current value or not (and may be color the view appropriately). So that you can set it from outside. Also replace a single button in widget's build()   with a row of  some buttons like stop/reset/lap... each doing its job/notifying parent and so that user can pause/restart each timer individually.  To reset all timers at once I would just recreate all of them in parent. You can have an array of widgets in parent and recreate lets say 1,3,5  by index/id not touching others.